# Subscribe to Rails Exceptions, using ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, exception, notifications

I am exploring ActiveSupport::Notifications, and would like to subscribe to Rails Exceptions, such as the ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError exception. Something like:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe /ActiveRecordError/ do |*args|

  # More code here ...

end
```

This subscription would exist in a 3rd party gem, so I don't have the flexibility to wrap my AcitveRecord calls with an "in app" begin/rescue/end. An underlying question, is are Exceptions considered and/or handled as events, that can be subscribed to?

Comment: Sudharsanan Muralidharan has a good Medium post on "modular error handling" in Rails, but if you don't have control at the ApplicationController level I'm not aware if a method https://medium.com/rails-ember-beyond/error-handling-in-rails-the-modular-way-9afcddd2fe1b

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are not handled as ActiveSupport notifications, a full list can be found here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html.

However, you can hook into the `ActionController` in a railties.

```rb
module YourGem
  module Rails
    class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
        config.after_initialize do
          ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
            rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

            private

            def record_not_found(exception)
              ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument "my.custom.event", this: :data do
                # do your custom stuff here
              end
            end
          end
       end
    end
  end
end
```

With this approach you might not even need ActiveSupport Notifications and just execute your code in the rescue?

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html